# Vue.js can not set options afer setting data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, axios

I try to set an option for my Vue component after getting my required data through an API. The data is set correctly when the Vue instance is created but it seems that does not affect my condition.

This is the snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.component("order-now", {

    delimiters: ["${", "}"],

    props: {
        dynamic: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        template: null
    },

    data() {
        return {
            order: '',
            startInterval: false,
        }
    },

    /**
     * created
     */
    created() {
        this.getOrderNow();
        this.$options.template = this.template;
    },

    mounted() {

        if(this.startInterval)
            this.$options.interval = setInterval(this.getOrderNow(),     10000);

    },

    /**
     * beforeDestroy
     */
    beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.$options.interval);
    },

     methods: {

        /**
         * getOrderNow
         *
         * Receive data from api route
         * and store it to components data
         */
        getOrderNow() {

            axios.get('/rest/order-now').then(({data}) => {

                this.order = data.orderNow.order;
                this.startInterval = data.orderNow.startInterval;

            }).catch(e => {
                console.error('Could not fetch data for order string.')
            });

        }

    }

});
```

I call my `getOrderNow()` method when the `created` hook is called. This works fine and my data is set.

As you can see, in the `mounted()` hook, I try to look if `setInterval` is set `true` or `false` and condionally set an option but `setInterval` is always `false`.

I thought that might has been changed after calling my method in the `created` hook but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.startInterval` is `false` because it probably never gets set to true at the time `mounted()` is applied. The thing is that you set `startInterval` after the promise returned by axios is resolved, which most likely happens after `mounted()`.

To solve this you can just set interval inside `axios.then()`.

Update after reading a comment (working demo):

```js
const API = {
  counter: 0,
  getItems() {
    return new Promise((fulfill) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fulfill(API.counter++);
      })
    });
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    interval: false,
    data: '',
  },
  methods: {
    fetchThings() {
      API.getItems().then((data) => {
        this.data = data;
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchThings();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.fetchThings, 1000);
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>
    {{data}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

And [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/dvt8awnm/)

Comment: This is what I have tried too. But when I call `this.$options.interval = setInterval(this.getOrderNow(), 10000);` inside `axios.then()` the milliseconds of the interval are ignored at it calls itself every milliseconds not every 10s.

Comment: Don't use parenthesis: `this.$options.interval = setInterval(this.getOrderNow, 10000);` I added demo to the answer.